# About not getting email address from twitter integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

can you please tell me what is the process of getting email address from twitter integration? i did it through fabric. For getting email address i followed all instruction that are given at https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform. And also get email from twitter. 
can you help me for further process? 
i follow this code.

```
 [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session) {
            NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
             NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userID]);
            [self usersShow:[session userID]];


            TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];

            NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                             URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                                      parameters:@{@"include_email": @"true", @"skip_status": @"true"}
                                                           error:nil];

            [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSLog(@"tMail%@",response);
            }];


        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

i got this response:

```
         {
"contributors_enabled" = 0;
"created_at" = "Wed Nov 30 11:39:55 +0000 2011";
"default_profile" = 1;
"default_profile_image" = 0;
description = "Software developer";
entities =     {
    description =         {
        urls =             (
        );
    };
};
"favourites_count" = 2;
"follow_request_sent" = 0;
"followers_count" = 6;
following = 0;
"friends_count" = 12;
"geo_enabled" = 0;
"has_extended_profile" = 0;
id = 424967484;
"id_str" = 424967484;
"is_translation_enabled" = 0;
"is_translator" = 0;
lang = en;
"listed_count" = 0;
location = "Nokha, Rajasthan";
name = "Muraree pareek";
notifications = 0;
"profile_background_color" = C0DEED;
"profile_background_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
"profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
"profile_background_tile" = 0;
"profile_banner_url" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/424967484/1432039697";
"profile_image_url" = "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1667595088/Image0236_normal.jpg";
"profile_image_url_https" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1667595088/Image0236_normal.jpg";
"profile_link_color" = 0084B4;
"profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
"profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
"profile_text_color" = 333333;
"profile_use_background_image" = 1;
protected = 0;
"screen_name" = Murareepareek;
"statuses_count" = 3;
"time_zone" = "New Delhi";
url = "<null>";
"utc_offset" = 19800;
verified = 0;
}
```

Comment: can u show ur tried code

Comment: post your code which you integrate

Comment: i updated this que with code

Comment: @lalitasaini Getting problem with clientWithCurrentUser. What is it please guide, do i need to import some class for this or something else please guide.

Answer (score 2):

[image: I think you probably swept your eyes across this a bit too quick]

1) Through your developer account you have to submit a request to Twitter to "whitelist" your app so that you can retrieve particular person's email. This is sort of a security check because of the history of user data in USA being sold to third parties illegally for e.g, and so Twitter protects its users from forced advertisement, spamming and anything possible with an email address that may annoy the user.

```
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials272
```

"Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please use this form."
Form: https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform394

[image: This form will get your app whitelisted based on a reply within 1-2 hrs or days depending on Twitter!]

Hope this helps you!